# Enviar dados de um formulário para uma janela modal

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário simples e ao submeter o formulário, ao invés de eu enviar para uma outra página "resultado.php", eu gostaria de abrir uma janela modal usando o bootstrap, para mostrar o resumo desta postagem e e possível, um link para copiar o resultado para a área de transferencia (contrl+c) . Como "carregar" os valores dos campos do formulário no modal ??

Comment: Você já tem o html do modal do boottrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Criando o model com os elementos que você deseja exibir, cada item do formulário é  só criar um ID pra cada e criar uma função JS no botão de "submeter" que atribuiria o valor de cada input do formulário para cada elemento do model.

**Exemplo:**

```
    <form>
        <input id="inputRandom" value="blabla"/>
        <button id="submit">Submeter</button>
    </form>

    <div class="modal">
      <span id="mostraValorInput"></span>
    </div>

<script>
     $("#submit").click(function (){
     $("#mostraValorInput").text($("#inputRandom").val());
     });

</script>
```